# How to Indicate Required Fields?

Tags: validation

What is the best way to indicate required fields?

Is a red asterisk beside each field's label enough?
Do you also need to explain with words what a red asterisk means?

What if all of the fields are required? Should you still have a red asterisk?

Comment: As a side note: limit the number of non-required fields as much as possible. If they are not required for the current task, then why are you bothering the user about them? Following this advice has the potential to increase your form conversion.

Comment: @Robert I agree, but this is out of my control.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861027/how-to-indicate-required-fields/52117397

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262922/whats-the-best-way-to-highlight-a-required-field-on-a-web-form

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this a pretty subjective question. I personally think that asterisks are pervasive enough that they don't need an explanation, but someone could make the opposite argument I'm sure. I like putting the word "required" in small text next to the required fields. It skirts the first issue and works well with screen readers. For some great examples of how this looks, check out this link:

http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/comment-form-styling.html

Something to avoid is coloring the background of the field itself. I've seen it on some sites and it's totally incompatible with screen readers, can give problems to colorblind visitors, and can even cause problems on poor LCD monitors.

Comment: The link you gave is great. Good examples. This is how I usually indicate required fields. I think the asterisk is almost univerally understood, except for really new internet users. That is pretty common in windows applications too.

Answer (score 6):

### Mark 'optional' fields, not 'required' fields

Warning: Nielsen Norman thinks opposite = asterix everywhere.
See theirs [article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/required-fields/) or [video](https://www.nngroup.com/videos/required-fields-forms/) and make your own opinion.

[image: DON'T: Mark 'required' vs DO: Mark 'optional']
**Source:** [Form fields — Required vs Optional](https://uxdesign.cc/form-field-required-vs-optional-9b4d7cdbf400) by [Jordane Sanson](https://twitter.com/JordaneSanson)

#### Why use optional fields is always better than required :

- An asterisk is obvious to you, not to everyone, believe me, there are always some who do not understand.
- The red asterisks make users more fearful, it increases the risk of errors and reduces the form completion rate.
- There are always more fields required than optional
- Less visual noise on your form makes it more readable and therefore faster to complete

**Studies:**

1. [Web form design guidelines: an eyetracking study](https://www.cxpartners.co.uk/our-thinking/web_forms_design_guidelines_an_eyetracking_study/) by *cxpartners* **see Guideline 5**
2. [Marking Required Fields in Online Forms](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/required-fields/) by Nielsen Norman Group

Comment: There's also a [UX blog post from 2010](http://uxmovement.com/forms/always-mark-optional-form-fields-not-required-ones/) recommending the option labels too. I found it via this [UX Stack Exchange answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/18216/3987)

Answer (score 0):

An asterik or a different font color on the label is general practice along with brief copy denoting what said variations mean.

I usually use an asterik.

Comment: Thanks. So you use an asterisk and state somewhere on the page that an asterisk means the field is required?

Comment: Yes thats what i do. Generally i state it near the top of the form, but near the bottom would work as well if the form isnt too long.

Comment: The accepted answer is more complete and provides a better alternative

Answer (score -1):

A red asterisk is a common method for indicating a required field.  It might also help to put something like

> [* Required]

At the top of the form.

Other methods I've seen include a red border around required items.

Comment: Careful with the red borders. It looks nice, but can be difficult for colorblind readers and doesn't offer anything for screen readers to consume.