# How to indicate required fields on initial form render, using Bootstrap 5 styling and Django?

Tags: django, bootstrap-5, django-bootstrap5

I am using Django 4.1 and Bootstrap 5.

I think I'd like to mark required fields in a form as required, or maybe optional fields as optional, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861027/how-to-indicate-required-fields).

Django/Bootstrap already styles fields as green/red after form submission, if a required field is missing, but my request is when the form is first rendered.

Could be with *s or with "(optional)" or whatever.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: add `required_css_class = 'required'` to form class then write proper css for `required` css class.

Answer (score 0):

A good option would be to [override default fields attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) of a form. You can use for `labels` to add `*` or `help_texts` to add `(required)`for instance.

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        labels = {
            'name': _('Writer *:'),
        }
        help_texts = {
            'name': _('(this field is required.)'),
        }
```